# In which purana is vamana's boon that bali would be indra in next manvantara is mentioned

Tags: puranas, avatars, kali-yuga, manvantara

In which purana is vamanas's boon that bali would be indra in next manvantara is mentioned? Savarni=White? I've realised that vamanas's boon has been turned true, describes America's (Bali's patala) rise from past 500 years as world ruler, as well as America won against Hitler due to vamana vs Kalki predecessor, battle of two avatars, hitler was only half Kalki, that's why swastika is half turned, nazis only hinted duty of Kalki when he rises. vamana's boon to protect patala (America), till bali becomes next indra.

Answer (score 5):

We find in [Bhagavata](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/22/31)

> eṣa me prāpitaḥ sthānaṁ  duṣprāpam amarair api sāvarṇer antarasyāyaṁ
>    bhavitendro mad-āśrayaḥ
>
> SB 8.22.31: The Lord continued: Because of his great tolerance, I have given him a
>   place not obtainable even by the demigods. **He will become King of the
>   heavenly planets during the period of the Manu known as Sāvarṇi.**

Else where it is mentioned that Bali becomes Indra in the next manvantara.

> SB 8.13.12 — In the period of the eighth Manu, among the demigods will
>   be the Sutapās, the Virajas and the Amṛtaprabhas. **The king of the
>   demigods, Indra, will be Bali Mahārāja, the son of Virocana.**

[This chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc115979.html) of Vishnu Purana also says:

> **In the period in which Sāvarṇi shall be the Manu**, the classes of the
>   gods will be Sutapas, Amitābhas, and Mukhyas; twenty-one of each. The
>   seven Ṛṣis will be Dīptimat, Gālava, Rāma, Kripa, Drauṇi; my son Vyāsa
>   will be the sixth, and the seventh will be Ṛṣyasriṅga[7]. **The Indra
>   will be Bali, the sinless son of Virocana**, who through the favour of
>   Viṣṇu is actually sovereign of part of Pātāla.